# How to run a complex awk script on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, awk

I need to run the following awk syntax on a remote machine in order to remove duplicate lines (on the remote machine):

I also put "\" before the "!", but it doesn't work.

```
 ssh root@$remote_machine "    awk '/^#/ || !a[$0]++' /tmp/file > /tmp/file.new"
-bash: !a[$0]++': event not found
 ssh root@$remote_machine "    awk '/^#/ || \!a[$0]++' /tmp/file > /tmp/file.new"

 awk: cmd. line:1: /^#/ || \!a[-bash]++
 awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ backslash not last character on line
 awk: cmd. line:1: /^#/ || \!a[-bash]++
 awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
```

Any idea, how to resolve this issue?

An example of my file:

```
# ssh root@$remote_machine "   cat  /tmp/file "
fref
ref
erv
rtgrvf
t
ttt
ttt
ttt
f
f
dd
dd
efcref
vgt
vrt
brye
nhrtuym
```

I also tried the following:

```
# ssh root@$remote_machine "    awk '/^#/ || "'!'"a[$0]++' /tmp/file "
fref
```

Comment: Make a script, scp it and run it there.

Comment: I want to avoid that , and this is very short line , to make a script is little clumsy

Comment: And dancing around quotes is elegant, I suppose. Handling files is less of a headache than quoting any day.

Comment: yes you have good point , but I prefer to run the CLI on remote machine ( i have some reasond for that )

Comment: You could swap " and ': `ssh root@$remote_machine 'awk "/^#/ || !a[$0]++" /tmp/file > /tmp/file.new'`

Comment: its not work from some reason its print only the first line in the source file

Comment: oh you need to quote the $: `ssh root@$remote_machine 'awk "/^#/ || !a[\$0]++" /tmp/file > /tmp/file.new'`

Comment: Look, how better is your post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes around the `!` to prevent `bash` history expansion and `\` to escape the `$`:

```
ssh root@$remote_machine "    awk '/^#/ || "'!'"a[\$0]++' /tmp/file > /tmp/file.new"
```

`man bash` explains why trying to escape the `!` using `\` does not work in your case:

> Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value
>   of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,  \, 
>   and, when  history  expansion  is enabled, !.  The characters $ and `
>   retain their special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash
>   retains  its special  meaning only when followed by one of the
>   following characters:  $, `, ", \, or .  A double quote may
>   be quoted  within  double quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If
>   enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an !  appearing in
>   double  quotes  is  escaped using a backslash.  **The backslash
>   preceding the !  is not removed.**

The character `\` will not be removed after escaping the `!`. This explains the `awk` syntax error that you obtain.

Comment: Gohu , see my update after example , this will print only the first string from the file